# Getting always empty file using the class FileDownloader in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, url

I'm trying to download a file from URL using the class FileDownloader in Qt (here it's description: https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL )

Here's the code that I use to download and save file:

```
FileDownloader *m_pMyCtrl;
QUrl myUrl("http://wiki.qt.io//skins/common/images/wiki.png");
m_pMyCtrl = new FileDownloader(myUrl, this);

QFile file("myfile.png");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
out << m_pMyCtrl->downloadedData();

qDebug() << m_pMyCtrl->downloadedData();
```

Then file "myfile.png" is appears, but it's always empty or contains four bytes (FFFFFFFF in hex). Application Output displays the following message:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: can not resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: can not resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The SSL errors aren't important here.  What is important is that you aren't waiting for the `downloaded()` signal to fire, so you're always going to get back an empty `QByteArray`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added connect to signal and now program works fine.